# Record audio from internal speakers of ios device

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to record audio from the speakers of the ios device.

Example, if I'm playing a video I would like to extract the audio from that video.

I'm sorry if this question is vague.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at `AVAudioRecorder` class, which is part of `AVFoundation` framework.

From Apple Docs:

```
An instance of the AVAudioRecorder class, called an audio recorder,
provides audio recording capability in your application.
Using an audio recorder you can:

- Record until the user stops the recording
- Record for a specified duration
- Pause and resume a recording
- Obtain input audio-level data that you can use to provide level metering

In iOS, the audio being recorded comes from the device connected by the 
user—built-in microphone or headset microphone, for example. 
In OS X, the audio comes from the system’s default audio input device as
set by a user in System Preferences.
```

For more informations [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/index.html)